# Function to calculate the percentage of values for each key of a dictionary in Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
[('2014', (105, 234)), ('2014', (2877, 1426)), ('2014', (73, 68)), ('2014', (134, 143)), ('2014', (166, 125)), ('2014', (2324, 2316)), ('2014', (679, 124)), ('2014', (6132, 1180)), ('2014', (1497, 1322)), ('2014', (10675, 10201)), ('2014', (5549, 4809)), ('2014', (410, 390)), ('2014', (2931, 2722)), ('2014', (378, 356)), ('2014', (14597, 1555)), ('2014', (361, 236)), ('2014', (7323, 2775)), ('2014', (13081, 3374)), ('2014', (22881, 4453)), ('2014', (3123, 149)), ('2014', (1160, 179)), ('2014', (6165, 872)), ('2014', (9592, 2738)), ('2014', (2925, 1049)), ('2014', (571, 81)), ('2014', (2441, 1000)), ('2014', (9457, 2839)), ('2014', (0, 0)), ('2014', (227, 105)), ('2014', (787, 304)), ('2014', (918, 266)), ('2014', (1043, 349)), ('2014', (299, 82)), ('2014', (88, 52)), ('2014', (88, 40)), ('2014', (21, 15)), ('2014', (58, 37)), ('2014', (57, 23)), ('2014', (72, 34)), ('2014', (96, 36)), ('2014', (10, 4)), ('2014', (32, 68)), ('2014', (4, 0)), ('2015', (86, 210)), ('2015', (3168, 1515)), ('2015', (83, 71)), ('2015', (122, 121)), ('2015', (136, 118)), ('2015', (2609, 2526)), ('2015', (648, 82)), ('2015', (6476, 1129)), ('2015', (1235, 1083)), ('2015', (10602, 10292)), ('2015', (4803, 4210)), ('2015', (298, 284)), ('2015', (2466, 2261)), ('2015', (304, 297)), ('2015', (15341, 1641)), ('2015', (364, 224)), ('2015', (8687, 3043)), ('2015', (12722, 3285)), ('2015', (24022, 3929)), ('2015', (3653, 168)), ('2015', (1374, 176)), ('2015', (7611, 781)), ('2015', (11347, 3177)), ('2015', (2966, 1097)), ('2015', (601, 88)), ('2015', (2468, 1039)), ('2015', (9142, 2858)), ('2015', (0, 0)), ('2015', (244, 98)), ('2015', (932, 239)), ('2015', (1266, 381)), ('2015', (1073, 415)), ('2015', (327, 87)), ('2015', (93, 18)), ('2015', (81, 21)), ('2015', (12, 6)), ('2015', (69, 24)), ('2015', (59, 32)), ('2015', (42, 13)), ('2015', (79, 33)), ('2015', (8, 3)), ('2015', (19, 16)), ('2015', (12, 0)), ('2016', (81, 183)), ('2016', (3790, 2066)), ('2016', (106, 103)), ('2016', (155, 174)), ('2016', (155, 164)), ('2016', (135, 89)), ('2016', (3115, 2987)), ('2016', (577, 90)), ('2016', (7076, 1660)), ('2016', (1425, 1262)), ('2016', (10895, 10575)), ('2016', (4607, 4110)), ('2016', (272, 262)), ('2016', (86, 59)), ('2016', (2372, 2151)), ('2016', (175, 202)), ('2016', (16766, 1813)), ('2016', (276, 149)), ('2016', (9191, 3474)), ('2016', (11795, 3186)), ('2016', (23420, 5041)), ('2016', (3941, 201)), ('2016', (1452, 154)), ('2016', (8242, 780)), ('2016', (11395, 3581)), ('2016', (2692, 1089)), ('2016', (613, 95)), ('2016', (2421, 952)), ('2016', (9059, 2826)), ('2016', (0, 0)), ('2016', (212, 90)), ('2016', (817, 321)), ('2016', (1807, 469)), ('2016', (722, 320)), ('2016', (511, 166)), ('2016', (173, 61)), ('2016', (91, 28)), ('2016', (18, 3)), ('2016', (77, 25)), ('2016', (106, 24)), ('2016', (31, 3)), ('2016', (120, 47)), ('2016', (4, 1)), ('2016', (14, 12)), ('2016', (21, 1)), ('2017', (78, 188)), ('2017', (3253, 1163)), ('2017', (84, 90)), ('2017', (79, 73)), ('2017', (156, 168)), ('2017', (135, 94)), ('2017', (3114, 3045)), ('2017', (364, 49)), ('2017', (10212, 2572)), ('2017', (2152, 1926)), ('2017', (12306, 11876)), ('2017', (4383, 3798)), ('2017', (164, 158)), ('2017', (109, 21)), ('2017', (2641, 2510)), ('2017', (129, 138)), ('2017', (18222, 1958)), ('2017', (332, 194)), ('2017', (8472, 3390)), ('2017', (11401, 3270)), ('2017', (22043, 4098)), ('2017', (4878, 990)), ('2017', (965, 87)), ('2017', (9394, 1061)), ('2017', (12806, 3141)), ('2017', (2375, 900)), ('2017', (427, 60)), ('2017', (4123, 835)), ('2017', (14295, 2601)), ('2017', (1, 0)), ('2017', (241, 96)), ('2017', (708, 208)), ('2017', (1584, 391)), ('2017', (788, 404)), ('2017', (287, 64)), ('2017', (131, 114)), ('2017', (87, 18)), ('2017', (21, 24)), ('2017', (74, 32)), ('2017', (111, 56)), ('2017', (71, 46)), ('2017', (135, 60)), ('2017', (12, 2)), ('2017', (14, 21)), ('2017', (7, 2)), ('2018', (94, 172)), ('2018', (3184, 1189)), ('2018', (78, 73)), ('2018', (157, 175)), ('2018', (192, 148)), ('2018', (2256, 2212)), ('2018', (297, 93)), ('2018', (8107, 2307)), ('2018', (2209, 1916)), ('2018', (13110, 12909)), ('2018', (4606, 4052)), ('2018', (111, 109)), ('2018', (4193, 3912)), ('2018', (174, 131)), ('2018', (18507, 1958)), ('2018', (328, 231)), ('2018', (7808, 3412)), ('2018', (10957, 3138)), ('2018', (20871, 4027)), ('2018', (4809, 312)), ('2018', (801, 93)), ('2018', (10102, 1218)), ('2018', (10664, 3014)), ('2018', (1661, 681)), ('2018', (418, 84)), ('2018', (2367, 829)), ('2018', (8859, 2707)), ('2018', (0, 0)), ('2018', (236, 98)), ('2018', (714, 211)), ('2018', (1692, 446)), ('2018', (819, 302)), ('2018', (289, 53)), ('2018', (46, 8)), ('2018', (137, 20)), ('2018', (29, 22)), ('2018', (71, 19)), ('2018', (116, 33)), ('2018', (81, 10)), ('2018', (104, 26)), ('2018', (5, 2)), ('2018', (10, 7)), ('2018', (8, 0))]
{'2014': (4, 0), '2015': (12, 0), '2016': (21, 1), '2017': (7, 2), '2018': (8, 0)}
```

In the first  line I have values of a key and tuple like `('2014',(105,234))`

Then I created a dictionary in the second line wherethe key is the year and the value is the tuple.

And now I want to traverse the dictionary and find the percentage of each  year according to the sum of the first value in division of the sum of the second value, and the percentage of these values for all years.

Example for the first year:

```
sum(105+2877+73+134...)*100/(sum(234+1426+68+143))
```

```
def dict_Read(dictionary1):
  dictPercent={}
  sum1=0
  sum2=0
  for key, value in dictionary1.items():
    sum1=sum1+value[0]
    sum2=sum2+value[1]
    #print(sum1)

    dictPercent[dictionary1[key]]=((100*sum1)/sum2)
  return dictPercent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating the dictionary you can sum all the respective values and then iterate to calculate the percentages

```
a = [('2014', (105, 234)), ('2014', (2877, 1426)), ('2014', (73, 68))......]
b = {}
for i in a:
    if i[0] not in b:
        b[i[0]] = (i[1][0],i[1][1])
    else:
        b[i[0]] = (b[i[0]][0]+ i[1][0], b[i[0]][1]+i[1][1])

#To calculate the percentages
for k,v in b.items():
    b[k] = (v[0]/v[1])*100

>>> {'2014': 273.019467702728, '2015': 292.30638550890825, '2016': 276.2228447178201, '2017': 294.9761501769503, '2018': 269.8237170305009}
```

Comment: I think `** 100` should be `* 100`.

Comment: @darth baba From your answer i understand i make a mistake in the creation of the dictionary.I will revised my question

Comment: If I understand the objective it is to compute the (100* sum(x[0])/sum[x1], which is not the same as the 100*sum(x[0]/x[1]), since (A + B)/(C + D) is not equal to A/C + B/D

Comment: I did calculate (A+B)/(C+D) and not A/B + C/D

Comment: @scoute21 what is the revised question? I calculated the percentages based on your example: sum(105+2877+73+134...)*100/(sum(234+1426+68+143...))

Comment: @darth baba The example i proposed is a step by step procedure and the result i give in the question at start was wrong.That means tha the dictionary i gave to you as input is not right, so I am gonna mark your answer as right :)  and ask a new question with the new dictionary